# How to extend vim editor to full screen in putty?

Tags: putty, vi

[image: Screenshot showing how the editor doesn't occupy full screen]

When I use vi or vim to edit files in putty, it only shows a limited lines and columns. So how to extend the editor to full screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely that the program does not know what the correct screensize is.  Usually the system can get this information from the terminal program.  But sometimes it cannot, or it is overridden.

Assuming that you are using some unix-like system, the `stty` command can show what the *system* thinks the screensize is, e.g.,

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
$
```

The `rows` and `columns` values are what the system thinks the screensize is.  If *that* is wrong, you can use `stty` to change them, e.g.,

```
stty rows 50 columns 132
```

but a better way is using `resize` (just by running it, it calls the same interface that `stty` reads).

However, `stty` may show correct values.  Your *environment* may override its settings with the `LINES` and/or `COLUMNS` environment variables.  (Those are longstanding legacy crutches for termcap applications).  Just unsetting those variables fixes *that* problem.

Further reading:

- [RFC 1073 - NAWS (Negotiate About Window Size)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1073.txt)
- [resize(1)](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html)
- [use_env(3)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-use_env) describes the environment variables
- [stty(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stty&sektion=1) tells how to set/get terminal settings

Comment: Thanks Thomas! A simple `resize` perfectly solves my problem.

Comment: Was looking for this for past 5 years

Answer (score 1):

Typing in terminal

```
resize
```

will recalculate the rows and lines given by command

```
stty -a | grep columns 
speed 38400 baud; rows 55;columns 138; line = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after a while discovered I had lines and rows set (`set lines=30` and `set columns=80`) in .vimrc file. Commenting them out (`"` starts inline comment in the vim-rc syntax)  fixed the issue.

Comment: Can you explain in detail how to edit this file? Please see [answer] and take our [tour].

Comment: that's VIM's configuration file. From VIM itself you can edit it by typing `:e $MYVIMRC`

Answer (score 0):

the best and easiest way of doing is create .vimrc file on your home directory then paste below content in file

```
set ai
set mouse=a
set incsearch
set confirm
set number
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set wildmenu
set wildmode=list:longest,full
set lines=80
set columns=80
```

Save the file and exit then reload the file on current shell

```
source .vimrc
```