# After resize, when change putty window size, a blank page appear

Tags: putty

I typed `resize` in putty window.
Then I `vi myfile`. Everything is fine.
Sometime I want to maximize or minimize my putty window.
But if I changed the size of Putty window, then a blank page will appear. I cannot see the content of `myfile`. How to get back to normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your earlier question *[how to extend vim editor to full screen in putty](https://superuser.com/questions/1031272/how-to-extend-vim-editor-to-full-screen-in-putty)*, PuTTY is not successfully passing the screen size initially (or resized) to the application.  Normally it would do this by sending the `SIGWINCH` signal to the program running in the terminal.

Not all implementations of `vi` handle `SIGWINCH`, although most of this you are likely to use do this (you did not say what type of system you are using).  You *could* be using one which does not, or it *does*, but is interrupted, but (since PuTTY is not successfully passing the screensize), is blanking the screen due to incorrect size.

If that is the case, you will simply have to exit `vi`, update the screensize and start over.